# Flask app regularly calling external function even when not in use

Tags: python, time, flask

The app I am writing involves scraping a website periodically and storing the data in a db to see how it changes over time. To this end, the scraping function would need to be called, say, once every day.

Using a `time.sleep()` call or any similar method of keeping track of time hijacks the Flask app and makes it impossible for a user to change the page they are viewing.

The only other method I have come up with to keep track of when to scrape requires a page to be reloaded:

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    if (time.time() - last_scrape) > 86400.0:
        scrape()
        last_scrape = time.time()
    return render_template("index.html")
```

However, this method has two problems:

1. In order to regularly scrape, the app requires that someone navigates to a page almost constantly.
2. When the time has elapsed and the scrape function is called, whoever is navigating to the page has to wait for the function call to finish before the page loads.

Is there any way to reliably update the scraped information every day without compromising the functionality of the app?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to scrape within a Flask view?

Set up a separate process to perform the scraping and store the details in the database. This script could easily be triggered by cron, or whichever task scheduler is available in your environment.

Then implement a view in your Flask app that queries the database and displays the scraped information as you like.

If you must implement the scraping within your Flask app, write it as a separate thread. It will spend most of its time sleeping and a small amount of time scraping the data and updating the database. Importantly it will not block the main thread in which Flask is running.